# How to modify checkbox inside the DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `DataList` control with `Checkbox`

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server" />
```

In `DB` table , column name IsActive contain the value 0 and 1 where 0 is active and 1 is in-active.

if the value of IsActive is 0 the `chkActive` is checked otherwise `chkActive` is un-checked.

I want to bind `checkbox` of the `Datalist` on page load for each row according to the Isactive status . and also update the values on update button click.

please help

Comment: I guess you need this ? http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Bind-ASP-CheckBoxList-within-ASP-DataList-1648.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("IsActive ").ToString()=="Flase" ? true : false %>'  />
```

The string values TRUE and FALSE can be converted to bit values: TRUE is converted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0.

```
in update button click 


  string id = string.Empty;
        string itmcod = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            foreach (DataListItem item in DataListSearchResult.Items)
            {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("chkActive");
                HiddenField ShowcaseID = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("HdnShowcaseID");

                if (chk.Checked==false)
                {
                    id += ShowcaseID.Value +","; 
                }            
            }

       //  Update the records with id  

        }
        catch
        { 

        }
```

you can also use id in `Array` format

Comment: the IsActive  column is bit data type

Comment: Thanks now its working but how to update the values if i change the checkbox checked ???